# Getting JSON value from HTTP Request using GSON with Java

Tags: java, json, http, request, gson

I need to get the lat and lng cords as separate string values. I decided to use GSON to help with this but am having issues getting the points. I'd prefer not to add any extra classes but it's not a deal breaker. I don't even care to use an easier solution without GSON if there is one.

Below is what I tried.

```
private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int cp;
                while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                  sb.append((char) cp);
                }
                return sb.toString();
              }

              public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
                InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
                try {
                  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                  String jsonText = readAll(rd);
                  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
                  return json;
                } finally {
                  is.close();
                }
              }
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, JSONException {

    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=Fmjtd|luu821ual9,8w=o5-94aaqy&location=1448south4thstreetlouisvilleky");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("results"));
}
```

I can get the results string but not just the lat or lng. Plus it uses extra classes I was trying to avoid. Below is what the JSON returned from the URL looks like.

```
{
    "info": {},
    "options": {},
    "results": [
    {
    "providedLocation": {
    "location": "address here"
    },
    "locations": [
    {
    "street": "address here",
    "adminArea6": "",
    "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood",
    "adminArea5": "city name",
    "adminArea5Type": "City",
    "adminArea4": "County name",
    "adminArea4Type": "County",
    "adminArea3": "State name",
    "adminArea3Type": "State",
    "adminArea1": "US",
    "adminArea1Type": "Country",
    "postalCode": "zip here",
    "geocodeQualityCode": "P1AAX",
    "geocodeQuality": "POINT",
    "dragPoint": false,
    "sideOfStreet": "N",
    "linkId": "0",
    "unknownInput": "",
    "type": "s",
    "latLng": {
    "lat": 90.227222,
    "lng": -90.762007
    },
    "displayLatLng": {
    "lat": 90.227222,
    "lng": -90.762007
    },
    "mapUrl": "http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=111111111,160&pois=purple4"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject o = parser.parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement latLng = o.get("results")
            .getAsJsonArray().get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject().get("locations")
            .getAsJsonArray().get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject().get("latLng");
```

Parse json String as `Jsonobject`, and get value one by one. but I think the fastest way is creating a model to map the Json String Object.

Comment: Ah great that worked. But how do I get just the lat in a String variable and the lng in a different string variable. I tried several things but no luck.

Comment: `o.get("results")
            .getAsJsonArray().get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject().get("locations")
            .getAsJsonArray().get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject().get("latLng").getAsJsonObject.get("lat")`

Comment: `o.get("results") .getAsJsonArray().get(0) .getAsJsonObject().get("locations") .getAsJsonArray().get(0) .getAsJsonObject().get("latLng").getAsJsonObject.get("lng")`

Comment: The above code should work, you need to refactor them. :)

Comment: That's how I assumed it would work but I get : getAsJsonObject cannot be resolved or is not a field on .getAsJsonObject.get("lat")

Comment: Nevermind .get("latLng").getAsJsonObject.get("lng") should be .get("latLng").getAsJsonObject().get("lng") ... Thanks!